# disabling and enabling enter keypress event in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {

        event.preventDefault();

        $("#j").focus();


      }


});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id = "form1" action ='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = 'i' id = 'i' autofocus>
    <input type = "text" name = 'j' id = 'j'>
    <input type = "submit" name = 'submit' value = 'submit'>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php


echo $_POST['i'];
echo $_POST['j'];


?>
```

In the above code, I initially disable enter key press event. I am using a barcode scanner which already gives a carriage return. This lets me focus to the next input field after the first input field is scanned using the barcode scanner. However i wish to submit the form when the second field is input with data through the scanner. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add **oninput** function to the input tag with id **j**

```
<input type = "text" name = 'j' id = 'j' oninput="clickSubmitButton()">
```

Then provide **id** to submit button.

```
<input type = "submit" name = 'submit' id='submitbutton' value = 'submit'>
```

At last add the javascript code to click the button automatically.

```
function clickSubmitButton(){
document.getElementById("submitbutton").click(); //id of the submit button to be clicked
}
```

Comment: Hey but there's a small error. The thing is the second field is taking barcode input in one go and submits the form but if i manually enter input it does not take the input value except for the first character.

Comment: fixed it! made the following changes to clickSubmitButton() function- function clickSubmitButton(){

$(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        document.getElementById("submitbutton").click();
    }
});
 
}

Comment: Nice. In the question you had mentioned input with a scanner. That's why I didn't include keypress.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to be compatible with multiple inputs is to focus on the next one, until there is no more input.

Plus, you do not need a submit button. But you can leave it.
Snippet here :

```js
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(e) {
 if (e.which != '13') {
   return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  var next = $(this).next("input[type='text']");
  if (next.length > 0) {
    next.focus();
  } else {
    $("#form1").submit();
  }
});

$("#form1").on('submit', function() {
 console.log("submitted !");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="/my/url" method="post">
    <input type="text" name='i' id='i' autofocus>
    <input type="text" name='j' id='j'>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey! it works when i run the code snippet here but it is not working when i run it on my local machine. Ive edited my post with the complete code.